# Get all mailMerge fields from docx using docx4J

Tags: java, docx4j

I have `.docx` file, containing `mailMerge` fields.
I want to extract all field names to `List`. 
I saw some examples of `dox4J`, how to replace these fields with mapped value, but I DO NOT want to replace them, I need to read them only.

Is there a semy easy way to do that using `docx4J`?

Comment: did you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/FieldsDiagnostics.java

You can also look at the code in MailMerger:

```
    // find fields
    ComplexFieldLocator fl = new ComplexFieldLocator();
    new TraversalUtil(shellClone, fl);      

    // canonicalise and setup fieldRefs 
    List<FieldRef> fieldRefs = new ArrayList<FieldRef>();
    canonicaliseStarts(fl, fieldRefs);

    // Populate
    for (FieldRef fr : fieldRefs) {

        if ( fr.getFldName().equals("MERGEFIELD") ) {

            String instr = extractInstr(fr.getInstructions() );
            String datafieldName = getDatafieldNameFromInstr(instr);
```

Comment: above correct link 
 https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/fa20692bf0b7df2676a6b9de2ca8d156f0570779/docx4j-samples-docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/samples/FieldsDiagnostics.java

Comment: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/fa20692bf0b7df2676a6b9de2ca8d156f0570779/docx4j-core/src/main/java/org/docx4j/model/datastorage/migration/FromMergeFields.java